# Crash on trying access a property of a customUITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a BOOL property 'isEditMode'

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isEditMode;
```

This is how I try to access this property in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell isEditMode]) {
    // do something
}
```

However my application crashes at the if statement with an error "[UITableViewCell isEditMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". What might be the reason?

Comment: did you @synthesize the property?

Answer (score 2):

The cell returned most likely is not of the type you are expecting.

Add a breakpoint at that if-clause line and do a `po cell` within gdb's command line. You may as well add a `NSLog(@"cell instance: %@", cell);` before that if-clause and check the log-output.